# Security w/ Router Behind a Router?

Tags: network, wifi, routing

I have a SMB (small-to-medium-business) router (router x) that my workstations run off of in my small business. I wanted to offer my customers wireless internet while they wait for service so I installed an extra wireless router (router y) laying around at home. I plugged router y into router x so router x with IPs on the 10.0.0.0 network are assigned to all the workstations and router y. So for example router y has IP 10.0.0.128 assigned by router x by DHCP. When a user connects wirelessly to router y they are assigned an IP by DHCP on router y off the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

My question is: will anyone connected to my router y on the 192.168.0.0/24 network be able to tunnel their way into my 10.0.0.0/24 network through router y?

This is a very similar question but the only difference perhaps is that it's a wifi AP and not another router.
[Attaching hotspot to existing network - can it be secured?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/attaching-hotspot-to-existing-network-can-it-be-secured)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can.

Based on network topology, your protected network should be connected as far away from the Internet as possible. By allowing router Y to be directly connected to router X, all the wireless clients need to do would be to run a trace route, and then they will find out that they are actually connected to your corporate network.

You can try to remedy this by reversing the position of X and Y in the network, so that the wireless clients are connected to the outermost network whilst your business network is in the innermost layer, eg.

Internet -> Router Y (wireless) -> Router X (business)

Or, you can keep the same configuration that you mentioned, but place router Y in the DMZ of router X. The DMZ should limit the wireless clients on router Y from connecting to the business network of router X.

Comment: So I tried running the traceroute and didn't see the the outer router. So back to associations described in the question, wirelessly connected to router y. But when I traceroute, I don't see the hop through router x, which should be the 10.0.0.0 network.

Comment: @gh0st: there are routers and network devices that block traceroute packets from returning to the initiating device. However, there are other means of determining the topology of the network, eg. a Nmap ping scan of the entire 10.0.0.0/24 subnet.